# Dinamic <Text> width in the middle of 2 components. React Native

Tags: react-native

i have this situation:

```
<View>
    <Button style={{width:40}}/>
    <Text numberOfLines={1}>....</Text>
    <Button style={{width:40}}/>
</View>
```

Is possible not set the Text Width and make it fill all the View free space automatically?(something like flex) I need also `numberOfLines` works as well.

Thanks

******* UPDATE **********

i need also for `TextInput` if i try to write the second button goes out out the screen.

```
    <View>
        <Button style={{width:40}}/>
        <TextInput numberOfLines={1}>....</TextInput>
        <Button style={{width:40}}/>
    </View>
```

Comment: Try adding `flex: 1` to both Button component styles. If that doesn't work, Wrap a `View` around each Button, and set those Views to have `flex: 1`

Comment: it works, if i put TextInput no. Going to change my question for TextInput also.